# Inverse of the function $ f(x) = 1 - 1/x$ for all real numbers except 0

Tags: functions, inverse

I got the inverse as $y = 1/(1-x)$ but this seemed a bit too easy. Can anybody confirm if I'm correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.$$\frac{1}{1-\left(1-\frac1x \right)}=x$$

Visualization:

[image]